# Thread, breakpoint

Tags: ios, while-loop, countdown

I've written this little program in objective c.

```
int x;
x=1;

while (x<60)
{

    self.jalo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", x];

    x = x + 1;
}
```

jalo is the name of the label.
it should be a clock which counts till 60. I know it still needs a wait order there. But when I wanted to run this, there always was like a "thread1: breakpoint2.1" at the line of the while.So it did only run till this line. but why? I really don't know what that means.

I hope somebody can help me. But thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What happened to the OP?  Now you see him, now you don't...

Answer (score 2):

*You are doing it wrong*.  Cocoa is an event-based system and you need to let the system process events, which means you cannot use loops like this and expect the label to update (or at least observe the text changes).

See [Main Event Loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/MainEventLoop.html).

Instead you can use a repeating `NSTimer` and change the label text each time the timer method is called.  This works *with* the event system and allows Cocoa to actually redraw the label allowing you to observe the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I won't analyze your code, which will not leads to an animated label because of event loop, see trojanfoe answer for more precisions about this point.

For me, it looks like you just set a breakpoint in Xcode.
You can access the breakpoint navigator from the seventh icon. Delete the breakpoints and try again.

[image]

Also, if the breakpoint is not an exception breakpoint, you can see within your code editor, represented by a blue arrow in the corresponding line.